# Encog compute/classify wrong training data

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, ocr, encog

My network: 33 * 61 (2013) input node. 2000 node in 1 hidden layer. 45 (for 45 char) output node.

```
BasicNetwork basicNetwork = EncogUtility.simpleFeedForward(trainSet.getInputSize(), 2000, 0, trainSet.getIdealSize(), false);
```

Building training set code (it is run inside a loop):

```
NormalizedField c = new NormalizedField(NormalizationAction.Normalize,"color", 255,0,1,0);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        BasicMLData data = new BasicMLData(width*height);
        for(int i = 0;i<width;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<height;j++){
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(i,j));
                double value = c.normalize(color.getBlue());
                data.add(i*height+j,value);
            }
        }
        final MLData ideal = new BasicMLData(charList.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < charList.length(); i++) {
            if (i == charList.indexOf(e)) {
                ideal.setData(i, 1);
            } else {
                ideal.setData(i, 0);
            }
        }

        training.add(data,ideal);
```

Training code:

```
int i = 0;
final ResilientPropagation rp = new ResilientPropagation(network,trainSet);
        do {
            rp.iteration();
            i++;
            System.out.println("Error rate: " + rp.getError());
            if(i > 10){
                i = 0;
                EncogDirectoryPersistence.saveObject(new File("myneural.eg"),network);
            }
        } while (rp.getError() >= 0.01 ) ;
```

I have trained for 45 chars with 300 pictures for each char(the images are monochrome so r/b/g value is the same) with the error rate is ~ 0.02.
But when the traning complete, it still can't compute/classify even the training data.
My test code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
System.out.println("Width: " + width + " Height: " + height);
BasicMLData data = new BasicMLData(width*height);
NormalizedField c = new NormalizedField(NormalizationAction.Normalize,"color", 255,0,1,0);
for(int i = 0;i<width;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<height;j++){
        Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(i,j));
        double value = c.normalize(color.getBlue());
        data.add(i*height+j,value);
    }
}
MLData compute = basicNetwork.compute(data);
```

But when i try to classify, the right char still have a very low value. I have tested with various chars (in the training set) but Encog always classify the wrong char.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start by replacing this line:

```
data.add(i*height+j,value);
```

with this:

```
data.add(i+ (j*width),value);
```

Comment: but i think it is the same ?